# What is "context menu" & method registerForContextMenu()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

In **Activity** class, there is method called `registerForContextMenu(View view)`.

The android document explains that this method is used to registers a **context menu** to be shown for the given view (multiple views can show the context menu).

- What does "**context menu**" mean? Does it mean the physical menu button or what?
- I also need some explanation about the method `registerForContextMenu(View view)`, it is not clear to me to just read the document online.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's basically a pop-up menu that is displayed when you long-click certain UI elements (usually an item in a ListView).

You should take a look at the [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) section of the Developer Guide.

Answer (score 7):

This is from Android Developers: [Menu -Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

*A context menu is a floating menu that appears when the user performs a long-click on an element. It provides actions that affect the selected content or context frame.*

Imagine that you want a conext menu in a listview

```
//Constants for context menu options
public static final int MENU_MARK = 1;
public static final int MENU_REMOVE = 2;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ...
    ...
    // Specify that your listview has a context menu attached
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

// here you create the context menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_MARK, Menu.NONE, "MARK");
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_REMOVE, Menu.NONE, "Remove");
}

// This is executed when the user selects an option
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_MARK:
        mark_item(info.id);
        return true;
    case MENU_REMOVE:
        delete_item(info.id);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```